# Very remote control of TV by smartphone?

Tags: remote-control, android-tv, smart-tv

After my wife's recent stroke she was left with cognitive problems and struggles even to use the big button TV remote control I've bought her. This means she sometimes loses the channel she wants to watch. I recently bought my first smartphone (a Samsung Galaxy J3). Is there any way when I'm out of the house and away from our WiFi signal for me to use my smartphone to take control of our TV in order to change channels for her? When I call her, she can answer my call using her big button (basic) mobile, but she is unable to make outgoing calls. She wouldn't be able to use voice control to change channels. Thanks.

Comment: You should try this : https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-remotely-control-TV-content-from-the-internet